# PayPal IPN - Notify Url

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

A quick question about PayPal's IPN. I am running 2 websites which would require a different IPN handler, e.g:

firstsite.com/listener.php

secondsite.com/listener.php

Does the 'notify_url' parameter override what has been passed in Selling Tools on my PayPal account? If not, how do I go about solving this, can I just disable IPN in my Selling Tools to get rid of the necessity to pass one listener?

I know that the 'return_url' parameter does not always override the pre-set value in PayPal account. At least it didn't for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the 'notify_url' parameter override what has been passed in Selling Tools on my PayPal account?.

Yes it does. Ditto the return_url. Works for me.